# Cannot install package FUSE

Tags: linux, apt, pop-os

Using Pop!_OS 22.04 LTS x86_64

```
sudo apt install fuse
```

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 pop-desktop : Depends: pop-session but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: gvfs-fuse but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: xdg-desktop-portal-gnome but it is not going to be installed
               Recommends: gnome-remote-desktop but it is not going to be installed
               Recommends: flatpak but it is not going to be installed
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
```

```
cat /etc/apt/sources.list
```

```
## See sources.list(5) for more information, especialy
# Remember that you can only use http, ftp or file URIs
# CDROMs are managed through the apt-cdrom tool.
# deb cdrom:[Pop_OS 22.04 _Jammy Jellyfish_ - Release amd64 (20230327)]/ jammy main restricted
```

```
cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*
```

```
deb [arch=amd64 signed-by=/etc/apt/keyrings/docker.gpg] https://download.docker.com/linux/debian bookworm stable
X-Repolib-Name: Pop_OS Applications
Enabled: yes
Types: deb
URIs: http://apt.pop-os.org/proprietary
Suites: jammy
Components: main
X-Repolib-Name: Pop_OS Release Sources
Enabled: yes
Types: deb deb-src
URIs: http://apt.pop-os.org/release
Suites: jammy
Components: main
X-Repolib-Name: Pop_OS System Sources
Enabled: yes
Types: deb deb-src
URIs: http://apt.pop-os.org/ubuntu
Suites: jammy jammy-security jammy-updates jammy-backports
Components: main restricted universe multiverse
X-Repolib-ID: system
X-Repolib-Default-Mirror: http://apt.pop-os.org/ubuntu

### THIS FILE IS AUTOMATICALLY CONFIGURED ###
# You may comment out this entry, but any other modifications may be lost.
```

It seems that i have encountering dependency issues while trying to install the FUSE package on my Pop!_OS 22.04 LTS system.

How can i fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Your dependencies are messed up and your pop-desktop installation is broken.

Run `apt get update ; apt get upgrade` and see if that resolves the issue. If not then it may be simpler at this point to backup your data and resintall POP-OS from USB/DVD.

If you are a masochist, then you might try to fix the dependencies yourself - try installing the listed "depends" packages:

```
apt install pop-session gvfs-fuse xdg-desktop-portal-gnome
```

If that does not work, then you'll need to downgrade pop-desktop to a previous version then repeat the apt install.